# Python replace() - how to avoid repeating replace()?

Tags: python, list, replace

There are some elements in the `sorted_elems` list which will be changed to `str` such as:

`sorted_elems = ['[abc]', '[xyz]', ['qwe']]`

I want to remove the defined characters - `[`, `]`, `'` and print the output below:

So the output should look like this:
`abc`, `xyz`, `qwe`.

My solution to achieve it was:

```
print(str(sorted_elems).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", ""))
```

And it works fine, but the question is how to avoid repeating these `replace()`?

Comment: What about using a simple `for loop`? Alternatively, you can define your own function that calls multiple times `replace()` and then use that function in your code.

Comment: Try using regex to grep values inside braces

Comment: Do you mean something like `for i in sorted_elems: sorted_elems.replace(...)`? If yes, it's not my point.I do not want to repeat the defined characters to replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.strip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip#:%7E:text=Join-,Python%20String%20strip(),of%20characters%20to%20be%20removed) instead -

```
sorted_elems = ['[abc]', '[xyz]', '[qwe]']

for i in sorted_elems: 
    print (i.strip("[]"), end=' ')
```

Output:

```
abc xyz qwe
```

Comment: Maybe a typo, but the last test case was `['qwe']` which this doesn't solve.

Comment: @blueteeth There's a typo in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex sub function inplace of the replace function.

```
re.sub(r"(\[|\]|')",'',str(sorted_elems))

>>'abc, xyz, qwe'
```

If you want each separatly :

```
re.sub(r"(\[|\]|')",'',str(sorted_elems)).split(', ')

>> ['abc', 'xyz', 'qwe']
```

Comment: how to make the regex for these characters, and could you provide me an example based on the code that I have posted?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new function that will clean the defined characters from a list.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution solution is quite a big hack and not very scalable. You are ignoring the fact that `sorted_elems` is a list, and that the last value in it is also a list.

I think the correct thing to do here is clean every element, and then return the list however is required.

The `clean_element` function needs to run on every element of `sorted_elems`.

```
def clean_element(elem):
    if not elem:
        return ''  # empty list or None or empty string
    elif isinstance(elem, list):
        elem = elem[0]  # get the first element of the list out
    
    return elem.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

Now we can apply that to every element, and return the list as required.

```
cleaned_elems = [clean_element(e) for e in sorted_elems]
print(', '.join(cleaned_elems)
```

I think part of the question was about a better way to get rid of stuff than `replace()`. There are two ways, `strip()` or `re.sub()`. `strip()` is my preference because nothing needs to be imported.

After cleaning the *structure* of the input, each element is either fully cleaned, or is surrounded by `[]`, which can be stripped.

```
    return elem.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

could become

```
    return elem.strip('[]')
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop would be fine

```
for i in sorted_elems:
     print(str(i).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", ""))
```

Comment: It is not the answer to question that I've asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate() with a translation table that removes the unwanted characters:

```
removeChars = str.maketrans("","","[']") # 3rd parameter is characters to remove
    
sorted_elems = ['[abc]', '[xyz]', ['qwe']]

print(str(sorted_elems).translate(removeChars))

abc, xyz, qwe
```